# avoid making copy of an eigen block that's repeated used

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Is it possible not to make a copy into `bounds` in the 3rd line below?

```
Eigen::VectorXd all_bounds(100);
Eigen::VectorXd values(10);
Eigen::VectorXd bounds = all_bounds.segment(20, 10);
values = values.cwiseMin(bounds);
values = values.cwiseMax(-bounds);
```

One way I can think of is to inline `bounds.segment(20, 10)` into `cwise{Min,Max}()` call, but it duplicates code between `cwise{Min,Max}` calls and becomes ugly when the expression to get bounds is longer than the toy example above.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre], to avoid confusion. I adjusted my answer regarding const-ness

Comment: Thanks chtz! I will use godbolt like you did next time! It's great that godbolt has eigen built-in.

Comment: I removed the `Ref` part from my question just to make the question easier to follow for future readers, as your answer is already very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++11 you can just write

```
auto bounds = all_bounds.segment(20, 10);
```

Otherwise, or if you want to avoid the (in combination with Eigen) potentially dangerous `auto` keyword, you can write

```
Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd> bounds = all_bounds.segment(20, 10);
```

If `all_bounds` is read-only, use `Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>` instead.

Godbolt-Link: https://godbolt.org/z/OzY759

---

Note that in your example, both `values` and `all_bounds` were not initialized (I assume just to keep the example brief).

Comment: Thanks! Yep, fixed the typo. I think I tried Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd>, but got errors like

Comment: I added a godbolt demo

Comment: thanks! looking into why I got the error as shown in the updated question...

Comment: ah, I think it is because in my case `all_bounds` are `const Eigen::VectorXd`... Is there anyway around it in that case?

Comment: Got it. Thanks chtz!